# GCP IAP Authentication won't get service account credentials unless using environment var pointing at local json credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iap

I tried Google's Java IAP authentication example for service accounts: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-java

This works well when there is a local service account json credentials file which is mentioned in the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path-to-file>`.

In another documentation page https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java it says the following:

> If the environment variable isn't set, ADC uses the default service
>   account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, and Cloud
>   Functions provide, for applications that run on those services.

If I don't provide the env var though then the auth library in the example seems to generate a different type of credentials than `ServiceAccountCredentials`, which leads to an error being thrown. I logged the credentials that are created and they are resolved to `ComputeEngineCredentials` which leads to this part of Google's example throwing the error:

```
if (credentials == null || !(credentials instanceof ServiceAccountCredentials)) {
            throw new Exception("Google credentials : service accounts credentials expected");
        }
```

In the scenarios I am working on I won't always have the option of uploading the json credentials file and running with that env variable and at any rate I would expect that a compute engine can identify as the service account in its configuration. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: The example should be updated to accept the different types of service accounts. This has been done for the Python examples. The reason for the different types is that the private key is not available when running on Compute Engine, App Engine, etc.

Comment: hi @JohnHanley. you're right, the python example seems more up to date, including the comment about the compute engine / service account requirements, and it works. I looked through the google Java libraries to try to implement the same mechanism but I didn't find anything that would help. thanks for pointing this out.